# Iterating structures array field's values

Tags: matlab, struct, matlab-struct

How to iterate/loop structures array field's values.

For 1x1 struct

```
student = struct();
student.name = 'jim';
student.gpa  = 1.9;
```

I do this :

```
fields = fieldnames(student)

for i=1:numel(fields)
  var =  fields(i)
end
```

But I don't how to iterate 1 x 2  :

```
student = struct();
student(1).name = 'jim';
student(1).gpa  = 1.9;

student(2).name = 'ryan';
student(2).gpa  = 1.5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have either another `for` loop

```
fields = fieldnames(student);

for k = 1:numel(student)
    for m = 1:numel(fields)
        var = student(k).(fields{m});
    end
end
```

Alternately, you can use the fact that the dot notation will create a [comma separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) and you can place them in either a cell array (for strings) or a normal array

```
names = {student.name};
gpas = [student.name];
```

I typically prefer to use the second approach most often for accessing the same field from a struct array.

Comment: I've just realized this *fields{m}* cell array, thanks again